# Asp.Net web API: Redirect from API path to Google Authentication page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, owin, google-authentication

I used the following [article](https://thompsonhomero.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/creating-a-clean-web-api-2-project-with-external-authentication-part-2/) to implement google authentication in my asp.net web api project. I followed the article and created a sample application. Now I have a simple test, as follow, but I am unable to proceed further

1. I hit the URL `/api/Login/ExternalLogin` in browser
2. It redirects me to google authentication page, where I login to google
3. It redirects me back to `api/home` (again API url), where I compare google returned identity in my local database.

But my confusion starts here,
How can I use these API URLs in my angularJs application? If I hit `api/Login/ExternalLogin` in angular service, it will return me response of google authentication page?

How can I redirect browser if authentication from google is needed? What flow can I follow? Please help me, I am new to this concept.

Comment: This seems like an OWIN & Angular question. You might get an answer if you change your tags (remove C#, asp.net. Add AngularJS)